# Uncaught ReferenceError: signInWithEmailAndPassword is not defined at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (index.js:61) (anonymous) @ index.js:61

Tags: javascript, firebase

Problem:- I was trying to authenticate users while login via firebase authentication. but now while submitting the credentials it is not authenticating and showing the log error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: signInWithEmailAndPassword is not defined at HTMLFormElement. (index.js:42) (anonymous) @ index.js:42

below is html

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/main.scss">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="not-log-in">
            <form id="form">
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    
        <div id="logged-in">
            <h3>sucess</h3>
            <button onclick="logout()">logout</button>
        </div>
    
        <script src="funky/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

below is the javascript

```
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
    
    const firebase = initializeApp({
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });
    
    const notlog = document.getElementById('not-log-in');
    const login = document.getElementById('logged-in');
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        // const uid = user.uid;
        login.style.display = 'block'
        notlog.style.display = 'none'
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        login.style.display = 'none'
        notlog.style.display = 'block'
      }
    });
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        console.log(email," ",password)
    
       signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((user) => {
            // Signed in 
            // const user = usercred.user;
            if (user) {
              alert('sucess')
            }
            // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error',error)
        });
    })
    
    
    function logout () {
        signOut(auth).then(() => {
            // Sign-out successful.
          }).catch((error) => {
            // An error happened.
        });
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyIHz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't ***imported*** `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function, but you are trying to use it, which leads to your error.

Please import `signInWithEmailAndPassword` from `"firebase/auth"`. You can just include it inside your import statement, which is already there

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
```